# Intellij 13 gives errors when trying to install/launch android app to usb device

Tags: android, intellij-idea, adb

Whenever I try to run my android project to a usb device in intellij 13 the log gives the error below and can't install/launch the app.  The app launches fine in the emulator. I'm on a Mac.

```
//Log

Launching application: com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n "com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.app/.MainActivity }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.app/.MainActivity } from null (pid=27490, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10222
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1790)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:463)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:108)
at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:81)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:235)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exported

Comment: I'm still getting the same  error with android:exported="true">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project was missing this code by default

```
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

This is fixed in Intellij IDEA 13.0.1

Comment: In my case the solution was:
Run > Edit Configurations > Android > Activity > Launch default activity